# How to wait until there is no span tag with attribute ready_to_send or in other words span tag having attribute sent

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriverwait

I am using `Selenium` with `Java`.

There are many `divisions (divs)` with same `class` but `spans` `attributes` are different...

Example HTML :

```
<div class="message_bubble">
    <span data-icon="ready_to_send" class="">
        .....
        .....
    </span>
</div>

// another div with same class="message_bubble"

<div class="message_bubble">
    <span data-icon="sent" class="">
        .....
        .....
    </span>
</div>

// again div with same class="message_bubble"

<div class="message_bubble">
    <span data-icon="received" class="">
        .....
        .....
    </span>
</div>

// There are many divs as such
```

When `ready_to_send` is sent to server then its span `attribute` becomes `sent`.

How to make driver wait until there is no division having span attribute `ready_to_send` or in other words all divisions having span `attribute` `sent`.

My non-working code is :

```
private Boolean GetStatus()
{
    WebDriverWait UntilSent = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);

    Boolean Status;

    Status = UntilSent.until(new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>()
    {
        public Boolean apply(WebDriver driver) 
        {
            //int elementCount = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//span[@data-icon='ready_to_send']")).size();

            int elementCount = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='message_bubble']/span[@data-icon='ready_to_send']")).size();
            System.out.println("UNSENT count is.... : "+elementCount);

            if (elementCount == 0)
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }
    });

return Status;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this:

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.numberOfElementsToBeLessThan(By.xpath("//div[@class='message_bubble']/span[@data-icon='ready_to_send']"), 1));
```

this will wait until no elements under following xpath will be found.

Note: you have to add some imports:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
```

in your code it would be like this:

```
private Boolean GetStatus()
{
    try {
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.numberOfElementsToBeLessThan(By.xpath("//div[@class='message_bubble']/span[@data-icon='ready_to_send']"), 1));
        return true;
    }catch (Exception e){
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes it helped a lot. Accepting as answer with upvote.

Answer (score 2):

To invoke a *waiter* until there is no `<span>` tag with *attribute* `ready_to_send` you can induce *WebDriverwait* with the [not](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#not-org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedCondition-) clause of [ExpectedConditions](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html) along with the [presenceOfAllElementsLocatedBy()](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#presenceOfAllElementsLocatedBy-org.openqa.selenium.By-) method and you can use the following solution:

```
Boolean bool1 = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.not(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.xpath("//div[@class='message_bubble']/span[@data-icon='ready_to_send']"))));
```

Alternatively, you can also use induce *WebDriverwait* with the [ExpectedConditions](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html) clause [invisibilityOfAllElements()](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#invisibilityOfAllElements-org.openqa.selenium.WebElement...-) method and you can use the following solution:

```
Boolean bool2 = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfAllElements(driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='message_bubble']/span[@data-icon='ready_to_send']"))));
```

Comment: It helped a lot too. Upvoting too as for giving your valuable time, to read, and support. Thank you.